# How to gray out text in SublimeText?

Tags: sublimetext

What I want to do is gray out text with a pound sign (#) in SublimeText, therefore the code will not be read over. This used to be a feature, but no longer works, however.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the how to comment out in Python using Sublime text? You can just select the lines you want to comment out and then press `ctrl + /` (in Windows) or `cmd + /` (in MacOS)